# Firebase progress not updating properly in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I cant get my progress to work in firebase

```
const uploadImage = async () => {
  if (imageFile) {
    const storage = getStorage(app);
    const fileName = new Date().getTime() + imageFile.name;
    const storageRef = ref(storage, fileName);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, imageFile);
    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        console.log("snapshot", snapshot);

        const percent = Math.round(
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
        );

        // setImageFileUploadProgress(percent);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error.message);
        setImageFileUploadError(
          "Could not upload image (File must be less than 2MB)"
        );
      },
      () => {
        getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
          setImageFileUrl(downloadURL);
        });
      }
    );
  }
};
```

The first callback with `snapshot` is getting called only twice: 0 and 100. I want the intermediate values too.

I looked it up on google, and it seems I am doing it correctly. Maybe I am missing some configuration in firebase, file is getting uploaded correctly though.

Comment: How big is your file?